# 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myfolder', 'templates'),], NameError: name 'os' is not defined - Django

Tags: python, django

I have installed python3, pip3 and created virtualenv for my project and then installed django. I have installed needed packages and when I am trying to run this command in terminal 
`./manage.py syncdb --settings=myfolder.settings.local`

I get this error

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myfolder', 'templates'),], NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

I have read some comments to add `import os` in top of my setting.py file an to add `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

I have that already in my settings file but still I'm getting same error. 
How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have `import os` at the top of your manage.py file? It needs to be imported in the same file that's being executed.

Comment: yes I do have @SNygard

Comment: can you paste the entire stack trace?

Comment: I have found solution. For my case __init__.py was not in right folder so I just copy and paste it and it worked :) @karthikr

Answer (score 4):

You have to `import os.path` in your settings.py file, where you have your templates settings.

```py
import os
...

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'DIR':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates_folder_name')],
    ...
}]
```

Comment: Note that the [question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287860/dirs-os-path-joinbase-dir-myfolder-templates-nameerror-name-os#comment73644115_43287860) state that the OP does in fact have ``import os`` in their file.

Answer (score 2):

**IN NEW VERSION YOU JUST TYPE A TEMPLATE FOLDER NAME IN DIR**

'DIRS': ['**templates**']

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is to import os at the top of your settings.py file

```
# settings.py
import os # new
from pathlib import Path
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been obtaining the same error so I just replaced `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myfolder', 'templates'),],` with `'DIR': ['templates']` and it worked.

You can also solve this error by just writing `import os` right after the path import line.

Answer (score 0):

in django version 3.1 . You have to import os at your setting.py file
Otherwise you can install Django version below 3.0

```
# settings.py
import os
```